# Checking UINT8_t values as a boolean?

Tags: objective-c, boolean, conditional-statements, uint8t

I have several UINT8_T values and I may be confused here but can I use their values as a conditional statement in objective C? so if I have 00000001 then bool digitalOutput1 should be set to true?

Sorry if this is unclear... Please feel free to ask for any clarification.

How I traverse the UINT8_T object is as such:

```
  uint8_t value = input.value; //This is a value from an outside source
  for(UISwitch *temp in switchArrayIn){
    temp.on = (value & 1)
    value >>= 1;
}
```

so I am shifting down each bit to check if each value has a 1 or a 0, and if it does have a 1 - turn on a switch output; if it does not - turn it off.

**Basically what I am asking is if I am traversing a UINT8_T variable/instance that has a value assigned to it, whatever that may be. Can I use it as a conditional statement in comparison to boolean values? i.e.;**

```
 bool test = TRUE;
    uint8_t = 00000001;
   for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
    if(test == (value & i)){
   // do something
}
```

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question, because it's very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolutely any scalar in a Boolean context in C. A value of 0 (which is representable by all scalar types) is treated as false, and any other value is treated as true.

Comment: So within my edited example, would this be a logical way to check that the first bit in an uint8_t object has been set to 1?

Comment: @Tukajo: Well, more or less. `00000001` isn't a normal way of writing the number 1 (Is it an octal 1 with a lot of unnecessary zeroes? I'm not even positive), and comparing the value against TRUE doesn't really do anything. I'd just do `if (i & 1)`.

Comment: well if the uint8_t value is constantly changing and I wanted to check which numbers were changing and take notice of that what would the best way to do it be.? i.e. one second it could be 00000001 the next it could be 10010000 the next 00111000...

Comment: would I need to compare the value of 2^i against the uint8_t object?

Comment: @Tukajo: Well, that's a completely different question, but to get a mask of which bits are different between two numbers, you XOR them.

Comment: Ah thanks, I was not quite sure what the specific question would've been to ask as I am a bit new to bit-wise operands. Thanks for the help, I'll look into XOR.

Comment: @Tukajo: It's just `oneNumber ^ otherNumber`. For example, 7 (binary 111) and 1 (binary 001) XOR to 6 (binary 110).